# How to generate .deb package from a repository

Tags: linux, debian, package, apt, deb

How to get a .deb package from a not yet installed program. for instance when installing transmission I type `sudo apt-get install transmission`, how to get a deb package with something like `apt-get deb transmission /root/Downloads`.
to use for off line installs.
I apologize for my English. Thank you all for you time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ~40,000 packages.deb can just be downloaded.

Search : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/transmission → all → https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/transmission/download

Download : `$ wget http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission_2.84-0.2_all.deb`

Easier : Buy the 13 DVDs https://www.osdisc.com/products/debian/v82

---

Comment: Good information right there, thank you. Sorry if it was a silly question,I'm still a newbie here :)